# MongoDb access issue from aws lambda - nodejjs16

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently working on a Node.js project using AWS Lambda, and I'm utilizing MongoDB driver version 6.3.0 to connect to MongoDB Atlas. However, when attempting to create a collection using the `db.createCollection(collection_name)` method, I've encountered an issue where the Lambda function exits without any reported errors, and the collection is not created.

I'm wondering if there are any specific privileges or permissions required for the MongoDB Atlas user in order to successfully create a collection. Could you please provide some guidance or suggestions on how to address this issue?

Thank you!

Any suggestion would help